How to upload files in Blazor with Radzen component without a controller?
I am using Radzen's RadzenUpload component for Blazor and am unable to trigger any events. It appears that upload using RadzenUpload needs a controller according to this guide.
But is there any way to do it without a controller? I am using Blazor server and I don't need a controller.

Took me a bit to figure out, but in the documentation it is the following example that allows upload without a controller:

<RadzenCard Variant="Variant.Outlined">
    <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Subtitle2" TagName="TagName.H3">Upload client-side without Url</RadzenText>
    <RadzenUpload Multiple="true" Change=@OnClientChange Style="width: 100%"
                  InputAttributes="@(new Dictionary<string,object>(){ { "aria-label", "select file" }})" />
</RadzenCard>

